# cosine function by Maclaurin series using for loop and stops when difference in error is already by what i desired

Tags: python-3.x

Can you help me code a cosine function by Maclaurin series. I want to eliminate inputting number of iterations. I just want it to keep going until i achieve my desired accuracy (in my code 0.000000000000001). Kindly answer simply coz im a real beginner in python.

```
from math import *
variable_x = float(input("Input for cosine function: "))
number = int(input("Input number of iterations: "))
cosine_x = 0
for number in range (0,number):
    old = cosine_x + (pow(-1, number)*pow(variable_x,2*number)/factorial(2*number))
    print(old)
    if 0 < abs(old - cosine_x) < 0.000000000000001:
        break
    cosine_x = old
print(number)
```

Result:
Input for cosine function: 5
Input number of iterations: 100
1.0
-11.5
14.541666666666668
-7.159722222222221
2.528397817460318
-0.16274663800705413
0.34693981189206935
0.276927936905926
0.28422084055031593
0.283625015089173
0.28366421413266923
0.2836620929723069
0.28366218903935225
0.2836621853444659
0.2836621854666513
0.2836621854631402
0.2836621854632287
0.2836621854632267
0.28366218546322675
18

Answer (score 0):

To avoid input the number of iterations, you just use `while` loop:

```
from math import *
variable_x = float(input("Input for cosine function: "))
cosine_x = 0
number = 0
while True:
    old = cosine_x + (pow(-1, number)*pow(variable_x,2*number)/factorial(2*number))
    print(old)
    if 0 < abs(old - cosine_x) < 0.000000000000001:
        break
    cosine_x = old
    number += 1
print(number)
```